# How to generate pdf report automatically in Dynamics NAV

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav-2013, dynamics-nav-2016

I have designed a report and i would like to save each report in pdf into a specifi folder. How do i achieve this using a codeunit or report?

```
Number:=50050;
 CustBill.RESET;
IF CustBill.FIND('-') THEN
tofile := DELCHR(CustBill."Customer No." +    FORMAT(CustBill.Date),'=','/\:.,') + '.pdf';
Filename := 'D:\Bills\'+'tofile';
REPORT.SAVEASPDF(Number, Filename,Runrpt)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. What is the problem?

Comment: It generates the file without the name of the customer and date. the file name is `.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `IF CustBill.FIND('-') THEN` if used without `begin` and `end` only related to the single next line of code. In your case this one `tofile := DELCHR(CustBill."Customer No." +    FORMAT(CustBill.Date),'=','/\:.,') + '.pdf';` This will probably cause this line to newer be executed.