# Save every record in the table as PDF

Tags: dynamics-nav-2013, dynamics-nav-2016, dynamics-nav-2015

The have a two records in a table called Bill Info,
I have designed a report to the table and need to save each record into pdf file in a specific folder.

```
CustBill.RESET;
CustBill.SETFILTER(CustBill."Customer No.",'%1',Customers."No.");
IF CustBill.FIND('-') THEN 

 Customers.GET(Customers."No.");
 IF Customers.FIND('-')THEN BEGIN

   REPEAT
  CustNumber:= Customers."No.";
  tofile := '.pdf';
  Filename := 'C:\reports\'+CustNumber+tofile;
  REPORT.SAVEASPDF(50050, Filename,Runrpt);
   UNTIL CustBill.NEXT=0;
END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate pdf report automatically in Dynamics NAV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807565/how-to-generate-pdf-report-automatically-in-dynamics-nav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess. Here I fixed it for you.

```
CustBill.RESET;
CustBill.SETFILTER(CustBill."Customer No.",'%1',Customers."No.");
IF CustBill.FIND('-') THEN 
 BEGIN //you missed this one
  CustLocal.SETRANGE("No.", Customers."No.");
  IF CustLocal.FINDSET THEN //use findset already its year 2016
   BEGIN
    REPEAT
     CustNumber:= CustLocal."No.";
     tofile := '.pdf';
     Filename := 'C:\reports\'+CustNumber+tofile;
     REPORT.SAVEASPDF(50050, Filename, CustLocal); //propper parameters
    UNTIL CustBill.NEXT=0;
   end;
 END;
```

Pay attention to this line

```
REPORT.SAVEASPDF(50050, Filename, CustLocal);
```

Depending on dataitems in report you may have to use `CustLocal` or `CustBill` variable as last parameter. It will be used as filterset for your report.

And one more thing. As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301166.aspx) says:

> The FileName parameter specifies a location on the computer running
>   Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server. If you call this function from the
>   RoleTailored client, such as from an action on a page, then use the
>   DOWNLOAD Function (File) to download the .pdf file from the computer
>   running Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server to the computer running the
>   RoleTailored client.

So don't look for your file on local machine where client is running.

Any other problems urged you to post the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807565/how-to-generate-pdf-report-automatically-in-dynamics-nav) twice?